# How to use a fetch ajax request with multiple input (Symfony)

Tags: ajax, symfony, fetch-api

I'm learning Symfony by myself and I followed a tutorial about ajax request (using fetch API) used for filtering ads.
My first input with checkbox is working : When I select a category (example : sports), only ads from this category are appearing on my screen.
But, my problem is, when I'm adding selected list as filters, it isn't working.
I click on the selected list, I see that the count of request is increasing, but I can't get the params of the concerned list in my URL, I think that's why It doesn't works but I'm a beginner so I don't know how to correct it.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english I'm not fluent.

This is my code:

Script.js :

```
    window.onload = () => {
        const FiltersForm = document.querySelector("#filters, div.select");
    document.querySelectorAll("#filters input, div.select").forEach(input =>{
           input.addEventListener("change", () =>{
               //On récupère les données du formulaire
               const Form = new FormData(FiltersForm);
               //On fabrique la queryString
               const Params = new URLSearchParams();
                   Form.forEach((value, key) =>{
                       Params.append(key,value);
                       console.log(Params.toString());
                   });
                   //On récupère l'URL active
               const Url = new URL(window.location.href);
               //On lance la requête AJAX
               fetch(Url.pathname + "?" + Params.toString() + "&ajax=1",{
                   headers:{
                       "X-Requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
                   }
               }).then(response => response.json()
               ).then(data => {
                   //On va chercher le contenu
                   const content = document.querySelector("#content");
                   //On met à jour le contenu
                   content.innerHTML = data.content;
                   })
                   .catch(e => alert(e));
           })
        });
```

AnnonceController.php

```
     
   #[Route('/annonce/all_annonces', name: 'app_annonce_all_annonces', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function all_annonces(AnnonceRepository $annonceRepository, TypeAnnonceRepository $typeAnnonceRepository, DepartementRepository $departementRepository,RobeRepository $robeRepository, RaceRepository $raceRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        //On récupère des filtres
        $filters = $request->get("listTypeAnnonces");
        $departements = $request->get("listDepartements");
        $races = $request->get("listRaces");
        $robes = $request->get("listRobes");

       $listAnnonces = $annonceRepository->getFiltersAnnonces($filters, $departements, $races, $robes);
        $listTypeAnnonces = $typeAnnonceRepository->findAll();
        $listDepartements = $departementRepository->findAll();
        $listRobes = $robeRepository->findAll();
        $listRaces = $raceRepository->findAll();

        //On vérifie si y a une requête Ajax
        if($request->get('ajax')){
            return new JsonResponse([
                'content' => $this->renderView('annonce/_content.html.twig', [
                    'listAnnonces' => $listAnnonces])
            ]);
        }

        return $this->render('annonce/all_annonces.html.twig', [
            'listAnnonces' => $listAnnonces,
            'listTypeAnnonces' => $listTypeAnnonces,
            'listDepartements' => $listDepartements,
            'listRobes' => $listRobes,
            'listRaces' => $listRaces
        ]);
    }
```

all_annonces.html.twig

```
    {% block body %}
<div class="container is-widescreen">
    <br>
    <h2 style="text-decoration: underline;">Toutes les annonces disponibles</h2>
    <br>
    <form id="filters">
            {% for typeAnnonce in listTypeAnnonces %}
            <p><input type="checkbox" name="listTypeAnnonces[]" id="typeAnnonce{{ typeAnnonce.idtypeannonce }}" value="{{ typeAnnonce.idtypeannonce }}">
            <label for="typeAnnonce{{ typeAnnonce.idtypeannonce }}">{{ typeAnnonce.libelle }}</label></p>
            {% endfor %}
        <div class="select is-multiple">
            <select multiple size="5">
            {% for departement in listDepartements %}
            <option name="listDepartements[]" id="departement{{ departement.iddepartement }}" value="{{ departement.iddepartement }}">{{ departement.libelle }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select is-multiple">
            <select multiple size="5">
        {% for robe in listRobes %}
            <option name="listRobes[]" id="robe{{ robe.id }}" value="{{ robe.id }}">{{ robe.libelle }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="select is-multiple">
            <select multiple size="5">
        {% for race in listRaces %}
            <option name="listRaces[]" id="race{{ race.id }}" value="{{ race.id }}">{{ race.libelle }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="columns" id="content">
        {% for annonce in listAnnonces %}
            <div class="column">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <figure class="image is-4by3">
                            <img src="{{ asset('imgAnnonce/first.JPG') }}" alt="Placeholder image">
                        </figure>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="media">

                            <div class="media-content">
                                <p class="title is-4">{{ annonce.titre }}</p>
                                <p class="subtitle is-6">{{ annonce.prix }} €</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <a href="{{ path('app_annonce_show', {'idannonce': annonce.idannonce}) }}"><button type="button" class="button is-fullwidth is-warning is-light">En savoir plus</button></a>
                            <br>
                            <time datetime="2016-1-1">Annonce postée le {{ annonce.dateCreation|date("d/m/Y") }}</time>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If I correctly understood, you cannot select multiple filters at a time, right ? If yes, this is normal as you must build your Ajax URL request fully before fetch it. Here you, loop through all filters, but you fetch them one by one. So here is my guess: If any filter state change, you query all filters and loop through all of them even if they did not change, you add all of them in your URLSearchParams object, then ate the end you fetch. You will have here all params

Comment: @Skuti Thank you for your answer but It doesn't work actually...